# Reloading labels when scrolling esri map

Tags: events, dictionary, esri, arcmap, arcgis-js-api

What I'm trying to do is reload my labels when the user moves or scrolls the map to a different position.  Currently when the user zooms in past a certain level the labels load and every thing works correct.  When the user starts to move the map to a different state the labels disappear and you have to zoom out and zoom back in to regenerate the labels.

I've changed onZoomEnd to update / update-end / load / onLoad

Here is the code:

```
    function initUI(graphics) {

    dojo.connect(globals.map, 'onZoomEnd', function () {

        console.log("Initial zoom level is :" + globals.map.getZoom());                        

        var font = new esri.symbol.Font(14, esri.symbol.Font.STYLE_NORMAL, esri.symbol.Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, esri.symbol.Font.WEIGHT_BOLDER, "Arial");            
        var gl = globals.featureLayers[1].graphics;

        globals.map.graphics.clear();

        if (globals.map.getZoom() >= 9) {                               

            console.log(codeID);

            for (var i = 0; i < gl.length ; i++) {                   

                var g = globals.featureLayers[1].graphics[i];

                if (codeID == 1 || codeID == 32 || codeID == 28 || codeID == 33 || codeID == 10) {

                    var strLabel = g.attributes.NAME + ":" + $.formatNumber(findFips(g), { format: '#,###', locale: "us" });//creates string label formatted
                    var textSymbol = new esri.symbol.TextSymbol(strLabel, font);//create symbol with attribute name 

                    textSymbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0]));//set the color
                    var pt = g.geometry.getExtent().getCenter(); //get center of county

                    var labelPointGraphic = new esri.Graphic(pt, textSymbol); //create label graphic 
                    //add label to the intended graphic                    
                    globals.map.graphics.add(labelPointGraphic);
                }

                else {                    

                    var strLabelPct = g.attributes.NAME + " : " + $.formatNumber(findFips(g), {format: '#,###.0', locale: "us"}) + "%";
                    var textSymbol = new esri.symbol.TextSymbol(strLabelPct);//create symbol with attribute name                                          
                    textSymbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0]));//set the color
                    var pt = g.geometry.getExtent().getCenter(); //get center of county
                    var labelPointGraphic = new esri.Graphic(pt, textSymbol); //create label graphic 
                    //add label to the intended graphic                    
                    globals.map.graphics.add(labelPointGraphic);
                }
            }//end for
        }//end if   

    });//end on zoom end
```

Comment: 1) Try using extent-change? 2) I'm a bit confused as to the point of the whole thing...if you only want stuff to display at zoom > 9, you can set that at the layer level. Otherwise...why are you doing all this instead of just adding `globals.featureLayers[1]` to the map itself?

Comment: Its three maps that when zoom in past certain level or scale the map changes.  Once you get to layer 1 the extent you see the labels and data is displayed. But if you start scrolling past the initial extent nothing else shows up.  Its to much data to just add globals.featurelayers[1] to the map initially.  Thats you its created with scales and rendered onDemand

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the new 3.7 Esri ArcGIS JavaScript API has a new LabelLayer that may help deal with your issue.  It doesn't have as many features but is a great start for a beta feature.

[Label Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/labellayer-amd.html)

Here is a block of code that I've used (written in 3.7).  It uses the new AMD style require and "dojo/on" to attach the updated event triggers to the map.

```
map.on('zoom-end', function() { 
    handleMapPanZoom(); // Turns some complex layers on and off.
    maxOffset = calcOffset(map); // Updates the max offset at each zoom level.
    for (var i = 0; i < lyrs.length; i++) {
        lyrs[i].setMaxAllowableOffset(maxOffset);
    }
});
map.on('extent-change', function() {
   handleMapPanZoom();
});
```

Comment: The approach I took was to use update-end.  This way once the layer finshed updating as long as it was on that zoom level it would load all the graphics again and again.  Its very similar to your map.on code thanks

Comment: Just be careful in terms of duplicating the graphic labels over and over again.  Depending on your code, you may want to either lyrGraphics.clear() if you are looping and adding graphics or check if the graphic already exists and skip adding it.